# Caching global data in an iis website

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis, caching

I have  READONLY object graph that is cached for one minute so that it can be used by all threads (Code below).

```
public class ObjectGraphCache
{
    static readonly Object storeLock = new object();

    public ObjectGraph AllForElection(int ElectionId, System.Web.Caching.Cache cache)
    {
        string key=string.Format("AllForElection{0}",
            ElectionId);
        int timout = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbCacheTimeInSeconds"]);

        if (timout == 0)
        {
            ObjectGraph graph = new ObjectGraph();
            graph.AllForElection(ElectionId);
            return graph;
        }
        else
        {
            Object obj = cache[key];
            if (obj == null)
            {
                lock (storeLock)
                {
                    obj = cache[key]; // In case another page got the lock first and your are queued (Ensures only one get per cycle)
                    if (obj == null)
                    {
                        // Not in cache
                        ObjectGraph graph = new ObjectGraph();
                        graph.AllForElection(ElectionId);

                        cache.Insert(
                            key,
                            graph,
                            null,
                            DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, timout)),
                            System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
                        return graph;
                    }
                }
            }
            return (ObjectGraph)obj;
        }
```

However I want to know : Why use the Cache object, when I more easily store the READONLY object as a static.  This stores a pointer to the heap, so when it is updated, threads still processing the previous pointers object will carry one fine with the old object, AND also I would not have to cast the object from the cache before returning it.  Anyone see any gotchas?

Comment: are you calling this method in a new thread ?

Comment: _italic_ @FarzinZaker I am not doing any explicit threading, but IIS itself is highly multithreaded, so I wanted to ensure there would not be any problems._italic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `storeLock`in an application variable

Comment: You will need to clarify this.  I meant this to focus on whether using System.Web.Caching.Cache was pointless (And to store the object in a static instead).  I thought that the locking strategy was good best practice.

Comment: your locking strategy works fine, but not when you have multi iis worker process. in that situation you need to put your lock in application variable to keep it safe enough. Just use Application["StoreLock"]